# Microsoft Forms , Flow and HTTP Post request

Tags: rest, office365, power-automate, o365-flow

I am learning MS Flow with a basic setup: a Microsoft Form is submitted and its data is sent to another server with an HTTP POST request.

Weirdly the POST data seems to not being sent with the request.

From the other side, I get no data at all though when debugging in Flow it says that all the data has been sent.

This has been driving crazy for the last few days.

Please see the attached screens, if you can spot anything I m doing wrong.

[image: Flow]
[image: Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this post due to my bad understanding of REST and HTTP requests. The endpoints was expecting normal HTTP POST requests (Querystring format: **var=value&var2=value**...)

As you can see, Flow HTTP is indeed sending a POST request but with a **JSON payload** while the server was trying to decode the common querystring format.

Thanks (I am leaving this here, as it may save someone time in the future)